# Vue - how do i structure my app in non-SPA?

Tags: vue.js

I added VueJS to my Django project, i just integrated it using webpack and django webpack-loader, but i'm very new to Vue so i have some doubts on how should my app be structured.

I have a `main.js` file, an `app.vue` and a folder of components that i created on my own. In this project it's Django rendering Vue on a template, so what i do is to render an html template and inside of it the Vue app.

Now i have some doubts about the structure: instead of loading the whole app, i load the app and choose the components i need according to the page where Vue is being used. Here is an example:

**myDjangoTemplate.html**

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

{% block content %}
    
    <div id="app">
        <someComponent />
        <anotherComponent />
    </div>
                
                
    {% render_bundle 'chunk-vendors' %}
    {% render_bundle 'main' %}

{% endblock %}
```

So for example i have a page where i need to load a datatable that i made with vue, in another page i need to load some forms i made with Vue. Of course in `table.html` i will only need to load the datatable component, not the whole app, and the same goes for the page where i need to only load the form.

Am i handling this right? Is this a bad practice for Vue?

Comment: Like mentioned by LeszekMazur, you will have to create a new Vue app on each individually loaddd HTML page. But of course, you do not need to register each component in each app. The creation should take very little code and then just register the relevant components. Move shared components into other file/s.

Comment: But i don't understand, what's wrong in always having the same app and then instead of creating another app i load the same app but with different components every time

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this approach, but you have some disadvantages. You cannot share the same in-memory data from page to page and the page transition is not as smooth as in a SPA. But mainly the first point. You need to put everything into a persisted store (e.g. LocalStorage), if you want to access it from another page (e.g. local settings, filter, language preference, etc.). These two instantiations are completely logically separated.

Comment: Fair enough! This was very helpful, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must to decide if you want SPA (Single Page Aplication) which is default for VUE, or multiple pages. If multiple pages, you should add separate vue app on each.

Comment: Thank you for your answe. What if i use it in multiple pages and every time i use the same app but with different components? Like in a page i do <div id="app"><someComponent /></div> and in another different page i do <div id="app><anotherComponent /></div>

Comment: It should work, but you must try.